# Why do Staking Rewards fluctuate so much?

Tags: polkadot, staking

When I look at my staking rewards, i can observe that the rewards fluctuate strongly.
Sometimes its `x` DOT per day, then the next day its just `x / 2` DOT.
Why is it fluctuating by more than 100% ? It feels like I'm doing something wrong.
Am I nominating the wrong validators?
Does the [staking dashboard](https://staking.polkadot.network/dashboard#/validators) help with getting more rewards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The staking rewards are coming from era points. The points can come from various sources, mainly including:

1. Authoring rewards, which is more or less equal over time
2. Doing PVF (parachain validation function) execution, which is very much not equal in the short time, but it does average out in the longer term. There could be slight variability based on the validator's networking hardware as well.

If you average your rewards over a period of 1 or 2 months, it should be more or less equal and the variability averages out.